# Derivation of a summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I understand that $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{\infty}$ $t(1 - p)^{t}$ = $\tfrac{1-p}{p^2}$, for mod(1-p) $<$ 1. However, I am trying to derive this fact and I'm not sure so please could someone help.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the geometric series for $\vert x \vert < 1$.

We have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \dfrac1{1-x} \text{ for } \vert x \vert < 1$$
Differentiating this, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} kx^{k-1} = \dfrac1{(1-x)^2} \text{ for } \vert x \vert < 1$$
Multiplying throughout by $x$, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} kx^{k} = \dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2} \text{ for } \vert x \vert < 1$$
Setting $x=1-p$, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k(1-p)^{k} = \dfrac{(1-p)}{p^2} \text{ for } \vert 1-p \vert < 1$$